# kubectl version : Error from server (Forbidden)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy my pods on kube8 cluster using jenkins job.
But when  check kubectl version :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11",
GitVersion:"v1.11.6",
GitCommit:"b1d75deca493a24a2f87eb1efde1a569e52fc8d9",
GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-16T04:39:52Z",
GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Error
from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh'
content='1;url=/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s'/><script>window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2Fversion%3Ftimeout%3D32s');</script></head><body
style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
```

And kubectl cluster-info

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
```

It is not getting connected with server.
I have exported all the required Environment variables such as AWS_KEY etc to access the cluster. When i ssh into machine and manually export env variables and check kubectl version , it works fine .

Comment: are you using AWS EKS? You need to create a secret file with your kubeconfig and add that in the job as well. If using AWS EKS you also will need the AWS-authenticator installed

Comment: No, I am not using AWS EKS. I have installed kubectl using commands in wesite. I have defined specific aws credentials only

Answer (score 1):

you must be using jenkins service account to deploy the pod. ensure the service account has proper roles and rolebinding attached to deploy the pods in the cluster.